# React.JS using a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

So I am building a simple React application. It is my first time using it. So I have built this component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class FeatureBlock extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
render() {
   //code here  
   return (
   <li className="work-list-item" id={this.props.id}>
        <Link to={this.props.src}>
            <div className="thumbnail-wrapper">
                <img width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height} src={this.props.src} alt={this.props.alt} />
            </div>
            <div className="work-info">
                <div className="work-content">
                    <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
                    <div className="excerpt">{this.props.contentClass}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Link>
    </li>
    );
}
}
export default FeatureBlock;
```

And I am importing this in my index.js file like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import test from "./test";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import FeatureBlock from "../FeatureBlocks/FeatureBlock";

class testing extends Component {
render() {
    return (
  <div>
    <div className="component-container jobs-listing-component contact-page-component full-width-bg">
        <test id="test-id" title="Test Title" titleDesc="" contentClass="">
          <div className="work-archive-component">
            <ul className="work-list">
              <FeatureBlock title="Test Website" id="test-id">

              </FeatureBlock>       
            </ul>
          </div>
        </test>
    </div>
  </div>
    );
}
}
export default testing;
```

This in my brain seems like the correct logic that will work but it is not working. Like I said I am very new and I am just trying to get something simple to work and connect the dots here. Any and all help will be great! Just asking for learning experience. Thanks!

BTW 
My folder structure is like this:

```
src  
--testing  
----index.js  
----test.js  
--FeatureBlocks  
----FeatureBlock.js
```

ERROR LIST:

[image]

Comment: What does "not working" mean here?  What error are you getting?

Comment: You expect `this.props` to contain a width height and so on, however you do not pass those props to `<FeatureBlock ... />`

Comment: Since you're just getting into React, look into Hooks instead of Classes

Answer (score 1):

Your `FeatureBlock` component expects a `src` prop (which is passed to a `Link` component - `this.props.src`) but you are never providing it when consuming your `FeatureBlock` in your `testing` component (see `<FeatureBlock title="Viiv Healthcare Product Website" id="viiv-healthcare">
</FeatureBlock>`).

You need to provide the `src` prop like this `<FeatureBlock title="Viiv Healthcare Product Website" id="viiv-healthcare" src={some variable} />`

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs as it seems that `to` property of `<Link>` component never get props value as you haven't defined in component consumption.

Whenever you try to use props it means that you are providing additional information to your component i.e.

You should pass props in a component as:

```
<FeatureBlock title="Test Website" id="test-id" src="pass prop value here"/>
```

Which you can use in a component as:

```
render() {
       // you can also destructure props as here  
       const { src, id } = this.props;

       return (
           <li className="work-list-item" id={id}>
               <Link to={src}>link text</Link>
           </li>
       )
}
```

You can deep dive into this here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

Whatever properties you are providing in FeatureBlock component, like

```
Link to={this.props.src}
width={this.props.width}
height={this.props.height}
src={this.props.src}
alt={this.props.alt}
<h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
{this.props.contentClass}
```

These all props you need to pass like this.

```
 <FeatureBlock title="Test Website" id="test-id" src='some-link-here' width='10px' height='10px' alt='img-caption' contentClass='some-contents-here'/>
```